# AngularJs: "standalone" directives and external data dependancies

Tags: angularjs

First of all I'm a newbie with angular so if the question is trivial forgive me but i tried google and angular docs but i could't find any clear example for my needs.

I'm trying to build an "standalone" directive module (complex UI control) which i want it to consume data from a configurable service/factory/provider.

I have a demo app and my real app each of which should have its own dataProvider (i.e hardcoded and REST API, same unit test common scenario i guess).

Which would be the correct way of setting a different data provider object to each directive from the app that is using this directive module considering it may have more than one instace on the same html as in the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body ng-app="demo" >
   <my-directive id="first"></my-directive>
   <my-directive id="second"></my-directive>
</body>
</html>
```

To be more specific think of a grid directive which would have a controller to keep some dinamically redering, handling events or things such as ordering, paging, etc. But as a UI-Control it has no data retrival logic, it just needs some object that respect an interface such as "getRows", "getPage"

My question is oriented to how can i inject / configure the dataProvider object inside the generic controller of my directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this is how you would do it.

Create your directive. At this point you can pass in data via the scope attribute. The = sign will provide two-way binding to a scope variable in the current controller.

```
angular.module('UI-Control', [])

.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      data: '=myDirective'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        console.log(data);
    }
  }
});
```

Then create your controller and create a scope variable that you will pass into your directive. Be sure to inject your stand-alone directive module.

```
angular.module('testCtrl', ['UI-Control'])

  .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.data1 = {
      something: "Something 1",
      somethingElse: "Something Else 1"
    }
    $scope.data2 = {
      something: "Something 2",
      somethingElse: "Something Else 2"
    }
  });
```

Now in your HTML you can instantiate your directive with the passed in data like this.

```
<body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <my-directive="data1" id="first"></my-directive>
  <my-directive="data2" id="second"></my-directive>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe i was not clear enough with my question. With your approach i think i would have to write a new Controller for every app that uses the UI-Control module but my Controller must be one that has the logic of the view and the access to the data retrival.

Comment: Ok to clarify, is this like a plugin kind of thing? Where you want to be able to reuse the directive, but have custom options passed into your directive? That is what I was showing, and your logic goes in your link function, or you could create a controller for the directive to do it in there.